# Laravel storage symlink image view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, symlink

I created a symlink to show images saved in the storage dir in my view.

For that I ran this command:

> ln -s /Users/myname/code/myApp/storage/app
>   /Users/myname/code/myApp/public/storage

That did create me a storage folder inside public, the storage folder contains a folder name images, which I want to show in my view.

I am trying to show them like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/app/' . $categoryValue->category_avatar) }}" />
```

But the image tag is still empty and I get this error message:

> GET
>   http://myapp.dev/storage/app/images/TpHsZhQBMVdihEtSwiPo6hz36l1hE2K5joFfaerB.jpeg
>   404 (Not Found

The path is correct but it still does not show the images.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like you've made the incorrect link. It should be

```
storage/app/public -> public/storage
```

(you've missed the **public** part). In order to avoid any errors with directories, you should use the special [Artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk):

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: Doing this `<img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $imageValue->image) }}" />` did not work although its the right path.

Comment: @35Hunne what does your variable `$imageValue->image` contain?

Answer (score 1):

Try a route:

```
    Route::get('storage/{folder}/{filename}', function ($folder,$filename)
{
    $path = public_path('storage/' .$folder.'/'. $filename);
    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        abort(404);
    }
    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);
    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);
    return $response;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You specified incorrect directory as source file while creating symbolic link, you should change:

```
ln -s /Users/myname/code/myApp/storage/app /Users/myname/code/myApp/public/storage
```

to:

```
ln -s /Users/myname/code/myApp/storage/app/public /Users/myname/code/myApp/public/storage
```

Or you can use the `storage:link` Artisan comand:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

And then, you can create a URL using the `asset` helper:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/file.txt') }}" />
```

Comment: Doing this `<img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $imageValue->image) }}" />` did not work although its the right path.

Comment: @35Hunne Did `$imageValue->image` include the suffix?